# Meaning of this dialogue in Fukuoka dialect

Tags: meaning, dialects

> A: 朝ご飯はなんだった？
>
> B: こげん大きか茶碗に水の**ごたまずかおかゆ**と、梅のあのやおか...

Is ごた＝こぐ（すごく） and　まずかおかゆ＝不味いお粥？

Comment: Hi, please try to give your question a meaningful title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A: 朝{あさ}ご飯{はん}はなんだった？
>
> B: こげん大{おお}きか茶碗{ちゃわん}に水のごたまずかおかゆと、梅{うめ}のあのやおか...

Not an expert on Fukuoka dialect, but I could somehow read B's line with no problems.

「～～ごた/ごたあ」 means 「～～のような」 = "**(just) like ~~**".  You might be familiar with the somewhat similar-sounding word 「[如]{ごと}き」 that means the same in Standard Japanese.

「水のごたまず**か**おかゆ」＝「水のようにまず**い**おかゆ」 = "***rice gruel that tastes as bad as water***"  (It means the gruel is very thin.)

Fukuoka has ***ka***-adjectives when the rest of the planet has ***i***-adjectives.

Other dialectal words used:

「こげん」＝「こんなに」

「大き**か**」＝「大き**い**/大きな」

「やお**か**」＝「やわらか**い**」

> "What did you have for breakfast?"
>
> "Terrible-tasting rice gruel as thin as water (served) in a bowl this big and (very soft pickled plum...)"